# How to get profile of an user from user id?

Tags: profile

We need to get the profile of an user from his user id details.
Please let us know.

Comment: 30 second googling is highly encouraged before posting =)
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18108/how-to-get-the-current-user-profile-in-apex-class

Answer (score 2):

Shortest way in Apex:

```
 Id Profile1 = userinfo.getProfileId();
```

OR another way

```
User currentLoggedInUser = [SELECT id, Profile.Name, Profile.Id FROM User WHERE UserID=:Userinfo.getUserId];

String profleId = currentLoggedInUser.Profile.id;
String profleName = currentLoggedInUser.Profile.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the general case, e.g. when the User Id is taken from the `OwnerId` field of an object:

```
Id userId = ...;
Profile p = [
        select Id, Name
        from Profile
        where Id in (select ProfileId from User where Id = :userId)
        ];
```

But if it is the currently logged in `User` you are interested in the `UserInfo` class has a [UserInfo.getProfileId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getProfileId) static method you can use to get the Id. You can just use that Id if that is all you need or you can query the `Profile` object by that Id to get other values.